# Why c++11 thread crash?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

Look the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void task(int index){
    cout<<index<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(task,1);
    thread t2(task,2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

The most time, the program runs normally, but sometimes it crashs? Why does it crash? I use C++11 thread in windows7, codeblocks.

The error is:

```
Assertion failed: ((m_->valid == LIFE_MUTEX) && (m_->busy > 0)), file C:/crossdev/src/winpthreads-git20141130/src/mutex.c, line 57
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in your compiler or standard library or pthreads implementations. I suggest making sure you're using the latest version of your compiler, standard library, and pthreads. If you're already up to date on everything, take some time to debug the issue (if you have the experience necessary to; this bug seems kinda hairy) to understand who's at fault and file a bug with the appropriate source.

Comment: `/src/winpthreads-git20141130/src/mutex.c` ---- I don't think this is c++ library...